# More than one quantifiers for one variable: $\forall x\exists x P(x)$

Tags: logic, predicate-logic, quantifiers

I couldn't find any definiton about this:

$\forall x\exists x P(x)$

Is here the for all or the there exists stronger?

Cheers

Comment: Only the existential quantifier matters, the universal is superfluous.

Comment: The "inner" quantifier $\exists$ bind the variable $x$ in $P(x)$; thus, the "outer" quantifier has no effect. The formula is simply : $\exists x P(x)$.

Comment: I have never seen expressions like that written down.  I would consider it incorrect to write that.  I guess I agree with the commenters above about the best way to interpret it if you have to give it some meaning.

Comment: yes, first I thought too: whats that and why?? I guess that's why I haven't found any definition for it... But it's a task given to me... it was not my idea.
Thanks for the advices.

Comment: @HughThomas It makes perfect sense and in predicate calculus this is a legitimate formula. The formula $\exists xP(x)$ is 'closed', $x$ is shielded. Since it is 'closed', you can quantify over whatever variable you wish, it is a formula of the form $\forall x\phi$.

Comment: @user3435407 Grab a mathematical logic book,there you will find that if $\phi$ is a well-formed formula where $x$ doesn't occur **free**, then so is $\forall x\phi$ and $\exists x\phi$. In this case, $x$ doesn't occur free in $\exists xP(x)$, it occurs, but not freely, it is bounded.

Comment: I bow to others' superior knowledge!  Thank you.

Comment: @HughThomas *different knowledge

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The formula as written is quite well formed; it just is not very human readable.

It is best practice to avoid reusing symbols for bound entities when nesting quantifiers.   Thus wise, confusion in the given formula may be averted by a change of symbols for the quantified entities within their own **scope**.

The entity in the predicate is bound to the scope of the existential quantifier.   As such it does not occur free within the scope of the universal.   We can change symbol for the entity bound within the *scope* of the existential quantifier, without affecting the symbol of the entity bound in the *scope* of the universal.   Thusly:

$$\color{red}{\color{black}{
\forall x \color{silver}{\big( \color{black}{\exists x \; P(x)}\big)} \;\equiv\; \forall x \color{silver}{\big(\color{black}{\exists y \; P(y)}\big)} \;\equiv\; \exists y \; P(y) 
}}$$

---

**Further**   Just to be clear, suppose we had a nested statement with more predicates, such as: $$\forall x\;\Big(Q(x) \wedge \exists x\; \big(P(x)\vee R(x)\big)\Big)$$

To preserve meaning of the statement, we do not touch any of the $x$ symbols that lie *outside* the scope of the existential quantifier when  we change the variable bound *within its scope*.

$$\forall x\;\Big(Q(x) \wedge \exists y\; \big(P(y)\vee R(y)\big)\Big)$$